# How do you implementing authorization on a local website (intranet) using active directory in the .net framework?

Tags: .net, authentication, iis, active-directory

A simple website has been created. It is going to be implemented in the companies network so that users can access and edit data. A group of users **(security group)** has been created for those that have access to the system.

Now a selection mechanism "**Manage Access**" will be used by the admin to **pull all allowed users from a database** and then the admin can decide which users have access to what content or page.

ie. only authorized users can access pages authorized to them from example a user "Jake" is a production manager and should only be able to access the Product Production page, where data entry into SQL will occur.

So each user will be able to access one or more pages. How would this solution be implemented using asp.net and active directory. **Authentication** is obviously **windows not forms.**

**The users that have access to a particular page will be stored in respective tables of a database**. I have looked into **IIS** and it seems that IIS manager can limit access based on active directory and everything I have mentioned can be controlled via IIS and there is no need for this "Manage Access" page, Am i right? Except for where this list of allowed users is stored so it can be used with IIS

If not how would I go about **allowing and disallowing** (displaying and not displaying) the different webpages on the website **based on active directory**. ASP.NET code would be helpful. If I'm way out of line with this please say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link to get the details on how to look at the Windows User Credentials from ASP.NET ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx#paght000025_authorizingwindowsusers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx#paght000025_authorizingwindowsusers)

Short and simple is to look at: User.Identity.Name which should give you the username (e.g. \

From there you can setup web.config files to allow / disallow pages or use custom logic to determine what pages can been viewed.